# Rendering content inside an iframe is not working in a Jupyter Hub Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab, jupyter-console

I have a webserver which is running locally. When I do a wget in my notebook with the localhost:portNumber url. It seems to work fine downloading the html file.

But when I try to render it in iframe. I am getting blank data as shown in the below image. 
Trying to figure out what is happening. It is not even showing any exception. :(

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your approach should work.  Another approach would be to save it to a file and then display that in an iframe (using curl because I'm on windows):

```py
! curl localhost:8080/index.html > ifile.html
```

then:

```py
%%html
<iframe src='ifile.html' width=200 height=200></iframe>
```